# Suppress warnings from file_get_contents()

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

i am working on a project ... i want to get file content of youtube url 
i used this code :

```
$url   = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'. urlencode($name).'?alt=json';

$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

but if the video does not exist or invalid ... 
i have error in this line

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

Warning: file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/sadsad?alt=json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

i want if the user post does not exist video ... link appears or anything happened but i want this warning to disppear

Comment: You can check it first with `is_readable($url)`

Comment: $json = @file_get_contents($url);   by this way you will not get error messages